# Check loaderror background image of figure element

Tags: jquery

Got this background image which needs to be checked with the function below (is image able to load). The function is not checking or grabbing the id to report. Also I would like to be able the function on figure-items which are loaded (loadmore) via Ajax.

```
<figure id="2756" class="postitem state-rest" style="background-image: url(http://www.loepfe-co.ch/Wetterdaten/TraisFluors/Bilder/bild.jpg);"></figure>

  function fitcam()
{
$("figure").css('background-image').on({
    load: function() {
        var source = $(this).css('background-image'); 

    },
    error: function() {
        pos3 = $(this).attr("id");
        reportcam();
        $(this).parent().remove();
    }
}); 
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no JavaScript callbacks for CSS assets, so you can't go directly on the background-image. Instead you could do something like this (as various jQuery-plugins like [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages) do):

```
// method to test if a background file is loadable
function bgLoaded( jqSelector, jqContext  ) {
    // default settings - change them for your needs
    var jqSelector = jqSelector || 'figure',
        jqContext = jqContext || false;
    $(jqSelector,jqContext).each(function() {
      var $figure = $(this), bgImg, bgImgUrl = $figure.css('background-image');
      // check if we have a background image, and the element hasn't been tested before
      if(bgImgUrl && !$figure.hasClass('bg-loaded')) {
        // use the css rule to extract image src
        bgImg = bgImgUrl.replace(/^url\(["']?/, '').replace(/["']?\)$/, '');
        // create a temp image element and run the tests
        $('<img/>').attr('src', bgImg).on({
          // in case of success remove temp object to avoid memory leaks
          load : function() {
            $(this).remove();
            // add a class to indicate that this element has been tested
            // you might also use a data-attribute for this
            $figure.addClass('bg-loaded');
          },
          // in case of error remove temp - and whatever your needs are
          error : function() {
            $(this).remove();
            // do what you want here 

            // I would prefer a display instead of removing, because removing
            // could cause flickering effects of the page.                 
            $figure.remove();}
        });
      }
  }); 
}

$().ready(function() {
    // use on load
    bgLoaded();

    // in case you load figures async you call 
    // the method in the success method of your request.
    // bgLoaded accepts a custom selector and a context 
    // so you could enclose the scanning to the ajax response.

});
```

You'll find a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gevu8ht9/6/) here - the url of the image is modified to test the error case.

Comment: thanks Axel, two questions: 1.) thought this error function was depreciated. See the one I was using. What is better? 2.) the figure is not removed on error.

Comment: Well it was an example to explain how to handle background-image load testing, not a complete solution. 1) Yes, correct, error is deprecated, I will update answer and fiddle. 2) see comment in code 'do your stuff here', that is the place where you could remove the figure - or do whatever. To solve AJAX - name the function and call it on complete.